# UI architecture issue new angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, architecture

Currently starting up a new project in *angular 5 with ngrx* and trying to figure out some architectural things.

The app should start with a page like some sort of dashboard. On top of the page you will have a bar with buttons which you can toggle some widgets(components).

The issue i am having now is i don't know which would be the best way to show these multiple components on the same page with that in mind that each of these components are living in a different module.

So in a nutshell the dashboardpage needs to show multiple components which can be hidden or shown via toggling the menu buttons on top, and each component lives in a different module. Actually each component will have some actions which will route you to a page in that module.

For example in my dashboard i will have a widget projects which contains a grid with all my projects and by double clicking a row i will get routed to the project page that lives in the projects module. I hope i was able to make myself clear. Thanks in advance for helping me in my search.

Thanks.

Comment: SO is a Q&A site. You aren't really asking an answerable question. Please reference [ask]

Comment: Question maybe more suited for an architecture question in SE https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @progmatico when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: Thanks @gnat, your link was actually helpful for me, too.

Answer (score 0):

This will be easy with angular. Any component can be inserted anywhere else in the application using it's `selector` which appears at the top of the .ts file for the component. It can be imported as simple `<html>`, i.e.
`<my-component>` attach the *ngIf directive to have it only appear when a boolean is true. 
`<my-component *ngIf="myBoolean">`
 then when a dashboard button is clicked set that `boolean` to true. to close it, set it to false. So your app.html file could look like this:

`<app-nav-bar (toggleOn)="setComponent($event)"></app-nav-bar>`

which is your navbar component will be. there can be an emitter called toggle on that emits on click there and you can handle it in a setComponent function in app. In that function:

```
toggleOn(componentName: string) {
  if(componentName === 'componentOne') {
    showComponentOne ? showComponentOne = false: showComponentOne = true;
  }
  //...for your components.
}
```

then in the html in app.html place your components and put an *ngIf on them tied to their boolean.

In the nav-bar component your event emmiter will work like this:
first here's a button which toggles on the component:

`<button (click)="toggle('component1')">Component 1</button>`

then in the .ts file handle this component in the toggle function:

```
toggleOn = new EventEmitter<string>();
toggle(componentName: string) {
  toggleOn.emit(componentName);
}
```

Using this strategy should solve your problem but there are many approaches. A good read on the many techniques to communicate data in angular comes from the angular docs. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction Read it with focus and you'll be a much better developer!